# In IntelliJ, is it possible to find usages of a typed method with a specific type?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, usability, structural-search

Say I have a typed method:

```java
public interface Foo {

    public <T> T bar();
}
```

In Intellij, can I search for the method usages only with a specific type? Say, only with `String`?

```java
foo.<String>bar(); // will be listed in the search result

foo.<Integer>bar(); // won't
```

Comment: Seems there's no built-in feature for that, so I've created [a ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-154740) for the IntelliJ team. Feel free to vote for it.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of disappointing you, I don't believe so. I've looked through the 'Find Usages' option, but with no joy. I think perhaps a standard text search is the way forwards for this.

Comment: You didn't :) I pretty much figured there's no option, just wanted to make sure. I think I'll open a ticket for them.

Answer (score 1):

This **is** possible, but it requires a little bit of work. Use `Edit > Find > Search Structurally` and type a search pattern like the following:

```
$a$.<String>bar()
```

Click `Edit Variables` in the Structural Search dialog, put `Foo` in the `Expression type (regexp)` text field and enable `Apply constraint within type hierarchy`. Click `OK` and then `Find` and all calls with <String> will be found, even where the type parameter is implicit, for example:

`String s = foo.bar();`